# Xamarin trigger on button not firing in a FreshMvvm / SwipeView context

Tags: xamarin, button, triggers, swipeview, freshmvvm

The almost identical setup but without the `SwipeView` context is working fine.
The trigger gets fired and I do "my thing".

See the  following xaml code + PageModel.cs code :

```
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <SwipeView BackgroundColor="LightYellow">
        <SwipeView.RightItems>
            <SwipeItems Mode="Execute" SwipeBehaviorOnInvoked="RemainOpen">
                <SwipeItemView>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" WidthRequest="60" BackgroundColor="LightGray" Padding="2,5,0,5" >
                        <Button x:Name="Btn_Assign" 
                                Text="{x:Static fa:FontAwesomeIcons.UserPlus}" FontSize="20" FontFamily="FAS" 
                                HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                Command="{Binding AssignCommand}"/>
                        <Label Text="Assign" FontSize="Subtitle" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </SwipeItemView>
            </SwipeItems>
        </SwipeView.RightItems>
    </SwipeView>
</DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

**PageModel.cs**

```
public Command AssignCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(ExecuteUpdateCommand);
    }
}
```

The `ExecuteUpdateCommand` function contains the actual code to be executed.
The `AssignCommand` function is never accessed.

Comment: Use [relative-bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings) with source and path.

Answer (score 2):

From your description, you need to use [Xamarin.Forms Relative Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings) to bind command for Button's Command, I do one sample that using SwipView in Collectionview, then delete current item.

```
<StackLayout>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding models}" SelectedItem="{Binding selecteditem}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <SwipeView>
                            <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                                <SwipeItems>
                                    <SwipeItem
                                        BackgroundColor="LightPink"
                                        Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.deletecommand, Source={x:Reference page1}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding Name}"
                                        IconImageSource="delete.png"
                                        Text="Delete" />
                                </SwipeItems>
                            </SwipeView.LeftItems>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Age}" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </SwipeView>

                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
```

You need to name ContentPage's Name

```
<ContentPage
x:Class="FormsSample.collectionviewsample.Page18"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Name="page1">

 public partial class Page18 : ContentPage
{
   
    public Page18()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new swipviewmodel();
       
    }      
}
public class swipviewmodel:ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<swipmodel> models { get; set; }
    public ICommand deletecommand { get; set; }       
    public swipviewmodel()
    {
        models = new ObservableCollection<swipmodel>()
        {
            new swipmodel(){Name="cherry",Age=28},
            new swipmodel(){Name="wendy",Age=28},
            new swipmodel(){Name="barry",Age=28},
            new swipmodel(){Name="cole",Age=28},
            new swipmodel(){Name="leon",Age=28},
            new swipmodel(){Name="leo",Age=28},
            new swipmodel(){Name="stfan",Age=28}
        };
        deletecommand = new Command((obj)=> {
            if(obj!=null)
            {
                swipmodel selecteditem = models.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == (string)obj);
                models.Remove(selecteditem);
            }                            
        });
    }
   
}
public class swipmodel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

The screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Cherry Bu, let me try this first.

Comment: @JoukePostma Ok, looking forward to your feedback.

Comment: "You need to name ContentPage's Name"
Yes correct!

Comment: Then I did the following:

<Button x:Name="Btn_Assign" 
Text="{x:Static fa:FontAwesomeIcons.UserPlus}" FontSize="20" FontFamily="FAS" 
 HorizontalOptions="Center" 
Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference serviceJobPage}, Path=BindingContext.AssignCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />

This is working.

Comment: @JoukePostma do you have any other problem?

Comment: Thanks @cherry-bu-msft
It is all working now.